# Form clean() method to prevent 'Cannot assign None'

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to make the following template for my 'add tvshow form': a title field, and a tvshow_id field. The user can enter a title in the title CharField and use an AJAX button to retrieve matches from my db. Upon clicking a match, the tvshow_id field will be filled using some jQuery magic. If not however, that should be fine too because then my form should create a new tvshow instance using the title string provided by the user.

However, I keep getting the following error:

> ValueError at /tvshows/create/season/
>
> Cannot assign None: "Season.tvshow" does not allow null values.

Suppose I have the following models:

```
class Tvshow(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)

class Season(models.Model):
    tvshow = models.ForeignKey(Song)
```

And this is my form. Note that in my form I state that the tvshow is not required, while according to my model it is. This is because otherwise, the field itself will raise a ValidationError.

```
class SeasonModelForm(models.ModelForm):
    tvshow = forms.CharField(required = False)

    def clean_season(self):
        tvshow_id = self.cleaned_data['tvshow']
        if tvshow_id:
            try:
                return Tvshow.objects.get(pk = tvshow_id)
            except Tvshow.DoesNotExist:
                raise forms.ValidationError("No tvshow with this ID was found.")
        else: return None

    def clean(self):
        """Assign a tvshow in case there is no Tvshow yet."""
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        if not isinstance(cd['tvshow'], Tvshow):
            try:
                cd['title']
            except KeyError:
                raise forms.ValidationError("Please provide at least a tvshow title.")
            else:
                cd['tvshow'] = Tvshow(title = cd['title'])
                cd['tvshow'].save()
        return cd
```

My guess is that the validation of Season.tvshow occurs somewhere before my code is ran, but I can't seem to trace it.

I would love your input, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value of `tvshow_id` from `clean_season`.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by making `clean_season()` return an empty `Tvshow()` instance and then made a small change to `clean()`. It is not the most beautiful code I have ever written but it get's the job done.

```
def clean_season(self):
    """Must return a Song instance, whatever the cost."""
    tvshow_id = self.cleaned_data['tvshow']
    if tvshow_id:
        try:
            return Tvshow.objects.get(pk = tvshow_id)
        except Tvshow.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("No tvshow with this ID was found.")
    else: return Tvshow()

def clean(self):
    """Create a tvshow in case there is no tvshow yet."""
    cd = super(SeasonMinimalModelForm, self).clean()
    if not cd['tvshow'].title:
        try:
            cd['title']
        except KeyError:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please provide at least a title.")
        else:
            cd['tvshow'] = Tvshow(title = cd['title'])
            cd['tvshow'].save()
    return cd
```